# Rails 5: How to include JS global functions with webpacker?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

Let's say I have to load a js function with turbolinks:

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
    myFunction();
  }
);
```

But the function is very large and I wanted to avoid to added it to *application.js*. Thus I succeded to import it with **exports-loader**, for example:

```
import { myFunction } from 'exports-loader?exports=myFunction!./file.js';
```

But how to import a global function like **window.myFunction** ?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (in *webpack.config.js*)

```
loaders: [{
    test: /\/myFunction$/,
    loader: 'exports?window.myFunction'
}]
```